# Using vector images with android:drawableTop before API level 21

Tags: android, svg, android-support-library, vector-graphics

I am working on an application that needs to run on Android devices all the way down to Android Gingerbread (2.3) and seem to have run into some issues displaying an SVG image.

I understand, the support library allows me to use vector images by dropping this line in my app level `build.gradle`:

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

and I can then use a variety of support library classes or the `android:srcCompat` to display an SVG in an `ImageView`

The issue you here is that I am not using an `ImageView` to display my SVG. I am using a `TextView` with the `android:drawableTop` attribute to display my SVG as in:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_no_notes"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_notepad"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse" />
```

Since `android:drawableTop` does not use the support library vector images, the app crashes at runtime on pre "L" devices. Is there a workaround I can use to get `android:drawableTop` working, or am I stck just splitting up the `TextView` and use `android:srcCompat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to use it with the system TextView. (Relevant source code: [5.1.1](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#841) / [4.4.4](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#810))

You could use a custom View class, but at this point I think you are better off using a LinearLayout with an ImageView and a TextView.

Comment: Ugh, I figured that this would end up being the answer. Thanks!